# alert() works while elem.classList.add() doesn't add the class at the li element

Tags: javascript, addclass

I want to add a class to every li in #tabs_ul when it is clicked, but it doesn't work. 
I tried to see if with alert() it would work and indeed it does. Why it doesn't do this?
I'm struggling to get out of this problem

```
<script>
function clickme(){
var elem = document.getElementById('tabs_ul').querySelectorAll('li');
for(var f = 0; f < elem.length; f++){
elem[f].addEventListener('click', changeclass);
}};

function changeclass(){
alert('cliccato'); // This is shown
elem.classList.add('active_tab'); // This doesn't work
};

addEventListener('load', clickme);
</script>
```

Here the code in the body

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="tabs_ul">
<li class=""><a href="#tabs-1"><strong>Description</strong></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#tabs-2"><strong>Gallery</strong></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`elem` hasn't been defined in the scope of `changeclass`

You can use `event.target` instead:

```
function changeclass(evt){
  evt.target.classList.add('active_tab');
};
```

Alternatively, you could bind the element to the function:

```
for(var f = 0; f < elem.length; f++){
  elem[f].addEventListener('click', changeclass.bind(elem[f]));
}};

function changeclass(){
  this.classList.add('active_tab');
};
```